# Cookie not being set on IE, but sets fine on chrome and firefox

Tags: cookies

I'm calling this code on IE8, and on firefox:

```
document.cookie = 'val=500; expires=Wed, 18 Aug 2010 09:06:21 GMT; path=/dir/257/the-quick-brown-fox'
```

It works fine on firefox and chrome, but not on IE. Anyone see whats wrong?

UPDATE:
if I don't put the path then it works in both browsers, but I'd like to be able to put the path:

```
document.cookie = 'val=500; expires=Wed, 18 Aug 2010 09:06:21 GMT'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to check would be the security settings on IE.  Maybe it's set (or defaulted) to not accept cookies.

Maybe an obvious thing, but somehow when you get deep into bug fixing the obvious things have a tendency to bite you.

Comment: This is exactly what happened on my case. Only noticed on a brand new installation of explorer 9 that comes with security enabled by default.